# If symmetric matrix $A\geq0$, $P>0$, does $APA\leq \lambda_{max}^2(A) P$ always hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

If symmetric matrix $A\geq0$, $P>0$, can $APA\leq \lambda_{max}^2(A) P$ always hold?

**Notation:**

$\lambda_{max}(A)$ means matrix $A$'s largest eigenvalue.

$A\geq0$ means matrix A is a positive semi-definite   matrix.

$P>0$ means matrix P is a positive definite matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by "can we get"?  Do you mean "is it **ever** the case that [inequality]" or do you mean "is it **always** the case that [inequality]"?

Comment: I revised the title for clarity

Comment: If that's the case, we can simply take $A = P = I$ ($I$ being the identity matrix).

Comment: it's too special, can other positive matrix rather than $I$ hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not always, the case. For example
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\1&1\end{array}\right), P=\left(\begin{array}{cc}100&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$$

Then
$$APA = \left(\begin{array}{cc}101&101\\101&101\end{array}\right)\not\le 4P$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A should be positive semi-definite. However, in your case, A is not.

Comment: Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thanks