# Proof for a bound $\epsilon > m$ such that $A^TXA \preceq \epsilon X$, where $X \succ 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, alternative-proof, spectral-radius

I'm interested in the following problem:

> Let $A,X$ be matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $X$ symmetric and positive definite ($X \succ 0$). Proof a lower bound $0 < m < \epsilon$ so that $$ A^TXA \preceq \epsilon X.$$

As illustrated in an [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2211078/586833) $m = \lambda_\max(A)^2$ is not sufficient even for $A \succeq 0$.

I came up with the following bound based on [inequalities for the trace of matrix product](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.636.8021&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

> If $ \epsilon > \lambda_\max(AA^T)\frac{\lambda_\max(X)}{\lambda_\min(X)},$ 
>   then $ A^TXA \preceq \epsilon X.$

The proof is given below.

Questions:

- First, I'm happy if anyone could point out flaws in the proof below.
- Are there better bounds for $\epsilon$ such that the matrix inequality holds?
- Is there a simpler proof of the given solution?

---

### Proof:

Let $\rho(\cdot)$ denote the spectral radius of a matrix and let $||\cdot||_F$ be the Frobenius norm. Then 
\begin{align}
A^TXA \preceq \epsilon X &\iff \rho (A^TXA (\epsilon X)^{-1}) < 1 \\
&\iff \underset{k\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} ||(A^TXA (\epsilon X)^{-1})^k||_F = 0.
\end{align}

We use the following [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2211078/586833):

> Let $A,B$ be matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $B \succeq 0$. Then
>   $$ \text{trace}(AB) \le \lambda_\max \left(\frac{A+A^T}{2}\right) \text{trace}(B) $$

We have 
\begin{align}
||(A^TXA (\epsilon X)^{-1})^k||_F &= \sqrt{ \text{trace} \left( (A^TXA (\epsilon X)^{-1})^k \right)^T \left( (A^TXA (\epsilon X)^{-1})^k \right)} \\
&= \frac{1}{\epsilon^k} \sqrt{ \text{trace} \left( X^{-1} A^TXA \ldots X^{-1} A^TXAA^T X A X^{-1} \ldots A^T X A X^{-1} \right)} \\
&= \frac{1}{\epsilon^k} \sqrt{ \text{trace} \left( X^{-2} \underbrace{A^TXA \ldots X^{-1} A^TXAA^T X A X^{-1} \ldots A^T X A}_{\text{positive semidefinte by definition}} \right)} \\
&\le \frac{1}{\epsilon^k} \sqrt{ \lambda_\min(X)^2 \text{trace} \left( AA^TXA \ldots X^{-1} A^TXAA^T X A X^{-1} \ldots A^T X \right)} \\
& \ \ \vdots \\
&\le \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon} \lambda_\max(AA^T) \frac{\lambda_\max(X)}{\lambda_\min(X)} \right)^k n
\end{align}

- The first equality applies the definition of the Frobenius norm.
- In the second equality we use that $X$ is symmetric and so is $X^{-1}$.
- In the third equality we apply the cyclic property of the trace and observe that the right part is positive semidefinite per construction.
- The first inequality applies the trace inequality, uses the fact the eigenvalues of the square of a symmetric matrix are the eigenvalues of that matrix squared and that the eigenvalues of the inverse of a positive definite matrix are the reciprocals of the eigenvalues of that matrix.
- For the last inequality we apply the proceeding approach successively for $X^{-2}, AA^T, X^2$, $A^TA$ and use that the eigenvalues of $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ are equal.

Hence if $\frac{1}{\epsilon} \lambda_\max(AA^T) \frac{\lambda_\max(X)}{\lambda_\min(X)} < 1$, then $\underset{k\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} ||(A^TXA (\epsilon X)^{-1})^k||_F = 0$.

Comment: The notation $ X \succ 0 $ does not mean that $ X $ is symmetric and positive definite. It means that $ X $ is only positive definite. In your problem are the $ A $ and $ X $ matrices symmetrical?

Comment: For this problem, $A$ is not necessarily symmetric, but $X$ is symmetric. I wrote symmetric positive definite in brackets since some people define positive definiteness more general for non-symmetric matrices. I edited it to make directly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked through your proof, but here is another way to obtain the same bound.

First, note that $A^TXA \preceq \epsilon X$ if and only if $\epsilon X - A^TXA \succeq 0$.
Thus, it suffies to show that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ so that the eigenvalues of $\epsilon X - A^TXA$ are all non-negative.

Now note that,
$$
\lambda_\min(\epsilon X - A^TXA) 
\geq \lambda_\min(\epsilon X) - \lambda_\max(A^TXA)
\geq \epsilon \lambda_\min(X) - \sigma_\max(A)^2\lambda_\max(X)
$$

Thus, if we pick $\epsilon \geq \|A\|^2 \kappa(X) = \lambda_\max(A^TA)\kappa(X)$ we have $A^TXA \preceq \epsilon X$ which is the same as the bound you obtained.

I will leave the proof of the first inequality up to you.

This is the best you can do using only the norms of $X,X^{-1},A$ and no information about the eigenvectors.
For instance, let $X$ be any positive definite matrix.
Then given any value for $\|A\|$ it is possible to pick $A$ so that this bound is tight.
In particular, $A$ will swap the eigenvectors of $X$ corresponding to the smallest and largest eigenvales and scale them appropriately.
Again, you should be able to show this based on the tightness of the first and second inequalities.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 
I was expecting a simpler proof. 
I think the key point that I was missing is: $\lambda_\max(A^TXA) = \sigma_\max(X^{-1/2}A)^2$.

Do you have some intuition why we should not expect to do better without using eigenvector information? In your comment: I guess you mean for a given value of $||X||$ we pick $A$?

Comment: Essentially, all of the inequalities are tight in the sense that there are $X$ and $A$ for which they are equality.

Comment: That makes sense. For a problem that I'm working on $A$ is given and I can only control $X$.